# Monitoring Commands Sent to USB Printer

Tags: windows, usb, printer, logging

I have a programmable barcode printer hooked up by USB.  I have managed to install fonts to it and get it to do virtually everything but recall the stored fonts.  However, this printer very under-documented, and the only way I've managed to get this to work so far is using a Test Print feature of one of their pieces of software.

Long story short, I was wondering if there was some way to essentially monitor the USB port that the printer is connected to (or monitor the printer itself, somehow) to "listen" to what commands are sent to it.  Is there some windows log file that could give me this information?  Or any other way for that matter?

Also, if it helps, I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SniffUSB](http://www.pcausa.com/Utilities/UsbSnoop/) works on Windows XP (but not later) and is free.

HHD [USB Monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/usb-monitor) and [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/) are paid products.

Here is a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315597/what-software-usb-sniffers-are-available-for-windows) listing a few more.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm looking at SniffUSB right now.  How can I get it to monitor the actual data that's sent to the USB port?

Comment: @ashays: It's been a while since I used it, but I think you tell it to install a filter for the device then turn on logging.

Comment: I figured out how to use it and it works perfectly!  Thanks.  This utility has been great in aiding my understanding of this printer.